# Capture iPhone screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using following code to capture screen. Before it was working fine but now its retuning nil image.I am using iPhone 5,5c and 5s.

```
+ (UIImage *)screenshot
{

        CGSize imageSize = CGSizeZero;

        imageSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
        {
            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, window.center.x, window.center.y);
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, window.transform);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -window.bounds.size.width * window.layer.anchorPoint.x, -window.bounds.size.height * window.layer.anchorPoint.y);

            if ([window respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)])
            {
                [window drawViewHierarchyInRect:window.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
            }
            else
            {
                [window.layer renderInContext:context];
            }
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        }

        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return image;
}
```

Comment: Learn to use a debugger, then step through your code and see what is going wrong. After that you will be able to ask a proper question with useful debugging information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I am using this code and its working good.

```
+ (UIImage *)screenshot:(UIView *)view
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screenRect.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);
    [view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this piece of code works for me. This code capture a screenshot of the view (`self.view` here) and all its subviews. Means, in one word, screenshot of the screen.

```
+ (UIImage *)screenshot {
   CGRectMake *captureFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; //The portion and size of the area, you want to capture. I have set it to the size of window
   CALayer *layer;
   layer = self.view.layer;
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size); 
   CGContextClipToRect (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),captureFrame);
   [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
   UIImage *screenImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   return screenImage;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the captureFrame here?

Comment: This is the size of the frame, I want to capture. Sorry, I didn't mention.

Comment: This is also giving me blur image.

Comment: What size image you are trying to produce?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that I use to capture a `UIView` into a `UIImage`.

```
+ (UIImage *)renderView:(UIView *)view toImageWithSize:(CGSize)size {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.);
  CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  [view.layer renderInContext:c];
  UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return viewImage;
}
```

And then you can have your `screenshot` method that uses the method above to render the `rootViewController` of the main window into an image:

```
+ (UIImage *)screenshot {
  UIWindow *mainWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.firstObject;
  UIView *mainView = mainWindow.rootViewController.view;
  return [self renderView:mainView toImageWithSize:mainView.bounds.size];
}
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: This is giving me a blur image.

Comment: I edited my answer to call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` in order to take into consideration the screen's scale factor.